# input password em css não funciona

Tags: html, css

Uso o mesmo código CSS tanto para o input "text" como para o password e no entanto para um funciona e para o outro não:(ver foto)

Código em CSS

```
#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="password"],
```

Código em HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Address" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="password" type="password" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: inclua o estilo do css

Answer (score 2):

Desde que os inputs estejam dentro de um container com `id="contact"`eles receberão o estilo definido no CSS

**Veja o exemplo abaixo:**

```css
#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="password"]
{
  width:100%;
  background: #f3ed86;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Address" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="password" type="password" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```